# Terraform aws_wafv2_ip_set delete ip on apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-waf, terraform-aws-modules

I have a resource aws_wafv2_ip_set that is used by many different modules.

```
variable "addresses" {
  type    = set(string)
  default = []
}

resource "aws_wafv2_ip_set" "ip_set" {
  ip_address_version = "IPV4"
  name               = var.name
  scope              = "REGIONAL"
  addresses          = var.addresses
}
```

I need to create different ip sets that will be filled by a dynamic script from our admin section or directly from AWS console (not from terraform).

The problem is that every single apply detect that the ip set is not empty (like the var address), and so it delete all ip address added by console or by script.

How can I add aws_wafv2_ip_set without delete ip address on apply?

Thank you

Comment: I removed attribute   addresses          = var.addresses, and now it  doesn't make changes to ip set. Is this the right way?

Comment: Wow, there are many no-nos in your question. You are creating a WAF rule with Terraform, yet it is changed with an external script or **manually**?

Comment: @MarkoE Yes. I only need to create an ip set. This ip set will be filled by a script or by console (it depends on the situation). I don't need to fill the ip's list on terraform.

Comment: Well, then you don't need terraform at all. You might as well use the AWS CLI or AWS SDK for PHP. Changing the stuff outside Terraform will of course cause it to not be aware of those changes. It defeats the purpose of infrastructure as code, especially the manual part.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, `adresses` is an array of strings and is `required`.

Why don't you just go with the tf example:

```
resource "aws_wafv2_ip_set" "ip_set" {
  name               = "example"
  description        = "Example IP set"
  scope              = "REGIONAL"
  ip_address_version = "IPV4"
  addresses          = ["YOUR_IP_1", "YOUR_IP_2"]
}
```

Comment: I need to add ips from a php script. With terraform I only need to create  a waf ip set but not the ips

Comment: Well, if you keep overwriting the `var.addresses` terraform will remove the old ones. You'd have to somehow keep the list of *all* IPs and *append* to it, not to create a new one.